# Display different ui on TV screen when connect with screen casting with android app in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-developer-api

I want to show a different UI when the app is casting a screen with a TV in android studio.

I tried a lot but haven't succeeded yet. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I'd be happy to help you.

1. First you must create a new file in the layout directory, for example: `custom_cast_ui.xml`.
2. In your activity you need to call `custom_cast_ui.xml` like this: `setContentView(R.layout.custom_cast_ui);`
3. If you need to call elements like `ImageView`, you can do it as normal, because the new layout has already been set. Like this: `ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.img_example);`

Comment: Thanx for your answer but i already did it with the help of presentation class.